# Select Data From a Database combine Table

Tags: php, mysql

results from the database

```
10000583221231 --> 10000583221233 --> 2014-02-10
10000583221231 --> 10000358040343 --> 2014-03-03
10000583221231 --> 10000583221546 --> 2014-03-21
10000583221231 --> 10000583221345 --> 2014-04-01

10000583221231 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-02-10
10000583221946 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-03-28
10000583221475 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-04-01
10000583221564 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-04-09
10000583221397 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-04-20
```

php code:

```
    <?php
include('db.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Aplicatie WHERE id_usr_1 = '10000583221231' ORDER BY date");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['id_usr_1'] . " --> " . $row['id_usr_2'] . " --> " . $row['date'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

  echo '<br>';

$result_1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Aplicatie WHERE id_usr_2 = '10000583221233' ORDER BY date");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1))
  {
  echo $row['id_usr_1'] . " <-- " . $row['id_usr_2'] . " <-- " . $row['date'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

and I need to combine them into a table in the following way:

```
10000583221231 --> 10000583221233 --> 2014-02-10
10000583221231 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-02-10
10000583221231 --> 10000358040343 --> 2014-03-03
10000583221231 --> 10000583221546 --> 2014-03-21
10000583221946 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-03-28
10000583221231 --> 10000583221345 --> 2014-04-01
10000583221475 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-04-01
10000583221564 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-04-09
10000583221397 <-- 10000583221233 <-- 2014-04-20
```

and must be sorted by date.

what should I do? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do the arrows mean in your data grids?

Comment: Look in that table belongs. The first table -->, the second table <--.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do 1 query, using `OR` in your `WHERE`

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Aplicatie WHERE id_usr_1 = '10000583221231' OR id_usr_2 = '10000583221233' ORDER BY date");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  $arrows = ($row['id_usr_1'] == '10000583221231') ? " --> " : " <-- ";

  echo $row['id_usr_1'] . $arrows . $row['id_usr_2'] . $arrows . $row['date'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

?>
```